# Color mixing within Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

When mixing pigment and when printers use CMYK, magenta and yellow can mix to red. Why is this not shown when a document in Photoshop is in CMY mode?

Answer (score 4):

Your colors seem very faded. Could just be the screenshot, but you must be doing something wrong. You use the word "overlayed". You shouldn't use the *Blend Mode* called *Overlay* to mix two CMYK inks like this. You shouldn't mix them by lowering the opacity of the upper layer either.

To mix yellow and magenta in a CMYK document, make sure that both colors are at 100% tint and set the upper layer's *Blend Mode* to *Multiply*. The result should look something like this (depending on which CMYK profile you use):

[image]

*Multiply* in CMYK mode means (perhaps a little confusing) that the CMYK numbers of the two colors will be *added*. So CMYK(0,100,0,0) multiplied on top of CMYK(0,0,100,0) becomes CMYK(0,100,100,0).

The same effect will come from setting the top object to *Overprint* in layout applications.

---

Regarding the gradient have a look at this gradient. Here I've used the method *Classic* which simply interpolates the colors from one gradient stop to the next:

[image]

As you can see on the *Color Samples* I've placed, the yellow ink simply fades from  100% in the left to 0% in the right end. And the magenta does the opposite. So in the middle you'll get CMYK(0,50,50,0) which isn't really a red color.

This is exactly as expected. A gradient *fades* from one color to the other. It doesn't *mix* them in the sense you expect.

If you want the gradient to become red in the middle, you must manually add a gradient stop in the middle with CMYK(0,100,100,0):

[image]

---

I notice that you use the term "magenta and yellow *pigment* mix to red". Don't confuse what happens when printing with CMYK halftone patterns with what happens when mixing physical paint.

In CMYK print the inks are never physically mixed in the same way as you mix two kinds of paint in a bowl. Halftone patterns are printed on top of each other which gives the *illusion* of them "mixing". Read about [subtractive color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_color).

Mixing physical paint is another thing. Here the pigments are actually mixed. The "color mode" of this is referred to as [RYB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RYB_color_model). But it hasn't been digitized in the same way CMYK has and isn't really something graphic designers use in their daily work.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of things going on in your examples

1. The colour stops in your gradient don't seem to be 100% C, 100% M and 100% Y
2. You also don't seem to be using the *Classic* gradient method, but probably the default *Perceptual*, or another method such as *Linear*. Use *Classic* instead, like this:

[image]

You can see some of the different gradient methods here. The **Classic** method will create the strongest magenta-yellow blend resulting in a stronger red.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

CMYK printing inks magenta and yellow are color filters which both remove wavelength ranges from white light. Red remains, it passes both inks from the white light source to the paper and then (reflected) to your eye. CMYK inks actually are not pigments. Generally we call pigments color materials which are not transparent like CMYK inks are (except black).

In a RGB computer screen magenta is made by sending from the same pixel blue and red lights. Yellow comes from green and red light sources. All together have red, green and blue. There's more red than others, so the result is a light tint of red.That happens if you mix by having 50% transparent top layer. You can get other mixes (including the red) by using different layer blending modes than "normal".

Removing wavelengths from white light with CMYK inks is one way to create colors. Adding together red, green and blue lights is another one. Both methods are widely used.

There's also 3rd way: Mixing opaque or only partially transparent pigments. There's no valid general rules for the results, they depend on the used pigment materials. In some lucky cases one may get something reddish by mixing yellow and magenta pigments. As well the result can be something else. But paint selling shops can make quite reliable colored paint mixtures when they obey paint manufacrurer's mixing guides and do not take along anything from other paint manufacturers.